# How to bring focused elements into view when behind fixed element

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with textboxes being focused, but hidden behind a fixed footer. Normally, focused elements outside the viewable area are scrolled into view by the browser. Is there a way to treat the fixed footer as something which decreases the view-height without actually decreasing the viewable area?

I would prefer to keep the `position: fixed;` styling, but understand it may be preferable (i.e. easier) to just have two non-overlaping containers.

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/WJvSU/1/

If you have the first textbox focused and tab through each textbox, you should reach a point where the next focused element is not visible, but hidden behind the footer. What I would expect is for the hidden element to be automatically scrolled into view.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `z-index:999;` to your footer element then it will keep it on top of everything else.

Comment: Have you tested this with fixed content? Provide an example

Comment: @Adsy, I amended the question to include a reference for what I am trying to achieve.